# Convert pandas column of Object dtype into time datetime (with micro seconds)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parsing

My df looks like this. I tried many ways to convert the time of:
`hour:minute:second microseconds`, but hit a wall. Below is the sample.df.

I need the Time and micro-seconds (the 3 numbers after `00:00:02 948`, so the micro seconds in this row would be: 948.

How to make another column of Time object that pandas will be able to work- like with fast vectorizing (not iterating) later on. I do not need year, month, day, date. Just need theTime, with microseconds, formatted in a way to be acceptable for work by pd, like making aggregated time intervals etc. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

```
idx,   time,   col2, col3,  col4, col5,  col6 
0   00:00:02 948    41   14   34      36    55
1   00:00:03 228    44  -12   32      41    55
```

Comment: `pd.to_datetime('00:00:02 948', format='%H:%M:%S %f')`?

Comment: yes, this worked with `df1['Time'] = pd.to_datetime( df1['Time'] , format='%H:%M:%S %f')` with the result of: `1900-01-01 00:00:02.948`. So it added: 1900-01-01, i guess some default. 
I was adding %F instead of %f, and also need to include the ':', as in the string object. This is a move forward, even though i will need to find a way to get rid of the default year 1900-01-01. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You only have a "timedelta", not a datetime. So by converting it to datetime, pandas assumes time after 1900-01-01, because thats the definition (timestamp of 0).

I did not completely understand how your output is supposed to look like, so feel free to ask how to change it if I misunderstood.

You can access attributes for minute/second/microsecond independently and format them like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["time"], data=["00:00:02 948", "00:00:03 228"])
df["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time"], format='%H:%M:%S %f').apply(lambda dt: f"{dt.minute:02d}:{dt.second:02d}.{dt.microsecond:06d}")
```

outputs:

```
           time
0  00:02.948000
1  00:03.228000
```

If you only want to get seconds and microseconds, just remove `dt.minute` from the formatting.

```
pd.to_datetime(df["time"], format='%H:%M:%S %f').apply(lambda dt: f"{dt.second:02d}.{dt.microsecond:06d}")

        time
0  02.948000
1  03.228000
```